# Logical error in my Randomization code for R

Tags: r, permutation

The trial plan is to have 6 participant per week, so we have a block size of 6. Each week there should be equal chance of each patient receiving either Treatment "T" or "L". The code below only gives equal number treatment for a total of 120 participants,( ie 60 for T and 60 for L).But I want it like this:
for each week, treatment should be like :TTTLLL,LTLTTL,LLTTLT etc.
Below is my code:

```
library("randomizeR")
N <- 120
K <- 2
groups <- c("T","P")
par <- pbrPar(N,K,groups = groups)
R<- genSeq(par)
getRandList(R)
saveRand(R,file = "C:/Users/dataList.csv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```r
N <- 120
set.seed(2021)
apply(replicate(N, sample(c(rep("L",3), rep("T",3)))), 2, paste, collapse = "")
#   [1] "TLLTTL" "LTTTLL" "TLTLLT" "TLLTTL" "TLLLTT" "LLLTTT" "TLLTTL" "LTLTTL" "TLTLLT" "LLTLTT" "LTLTTL" "TLLLTT" "LTLTTL" "TLTLTL" "TLLTTL" "LLLTTT" "TLLTTL" "TLLTTL" "LLTTTL" "TLTLLT" "TLLTTL"
#  [22] "TTLLTL" "LTLTLT" "TTLLTL" "TTTLLL" "TLLTLT" "LTLTLT" "TTLLTL" "TTLLTL" "LLTTTL" "TTLLLT" "TTLTLL" "LTLTLT" "TLLTTL" "TTLLLT" "LLTLTT" "LLTLTT" "LLTTLT" "TLTLTL" "TLTLTL" "LLLTTT" "LLTTTL"
#  [43] "TTLLLT" "TTTLLL" "TTTLLL" "TLLTTL" "TLTLLT" "TTLLLT" "TLLTLT" "LLTTLT" "TLTLTL" "LLTTTL" "TTTLLL" "TLLLTT" "TLLLTT" "TTLLLT" "LTLTLT" "TTLLTL" "LTTTLL" "TLLTLT" "LLTTLT" "LTLLTT" "LTTLTL"
#  [64] "LTLTTL" "LTLLTT" "LTLLTT" "LLTLTT" "LTTLLT" "LTTLLT" "TLTLTL" "TLTLLT" "LTLTLT" "TLTLLT" "LTLTTL" "TTLLTL" "LLLTTT" "LTLTTL" "LTLTLT" "TLTTLL" "TLLTLT" "LTTLTL" "LTLLTT" "TTLLLT" "TTTLLL"
#  [85] "TLLTTL" "LTLTTL" "LLTTTL" "LLTLTT" "TLLTLT" "LTTTLL" "LTTTLL" "LTLTLT" "LTTLLT" "TTLTLL" "LLLTTT" "LTLTTL" "TLTLTL" "LTTLTL" "LLTTTL" "TLTLLT" "TTLLLT" "LTTTLL" "LTTLTL" "TLLTTL" "TTLLLT"
# [106] "LLTLTT" "LLTLTT" "TLLLTT" "LLLTTT" "LTLTTL" "TTTLLL" "TLLLTT" "TTLLLT" "TLTTLL" "TLLTLT" "LTTLTL" "LLLTTT" "LTLTTL" "LLTLTT" "TTLTLL"
```

Comment: What you have is what I imagined... As it stands, I don't think we could do much better unless the OP adds some info.

Comment: @r2eVans, what i wanted is permuted block randomization with block size of 6 for treatments :" L" and "T". Each block will have 6 patients for a total of 120 patients.

Comment: Sorry, EbrimaComma, I don't understand if you're saying this *does* *does not* do what you're trying to do? If this isn't the expected output, then please be specific.

Comment: @r2evans, the output format is fine, but am expecting the get a total output of 120, since total number of patients is 120(N <- 120)

Comment: Change `replicate(10,` to `replicate(N,`?